# TreeView и меняющиеся UserControl

Tags: wpf, mvvm, treeview, usercontrol

Есть слева TreeView, а справа поле для UserControlов. При нажатии в treeView на элемент первого уровня (синий), то в поле должно показываться первый userControl. Если нажать на элемент второго уровня (красный), то другой user control. Как всё это реализовать используя MVVM?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Я бы вам советовал использовать `Prism` для этого.
Туториал на русском можно найти [тут](https://habrahabr.ru/post/176851/). Про навигацию - [тут](https://habrahabr.ru/post/182052/).

По факту при нажатии на любой из элементов TreeView просто навигировать на требуемый контрол с передачей необходимых параметров.

Comment: Да так и есть..

Comment: @Dindro `Prism` поможет вам в этом.

Answer (score 0):

Проще всего, наверное, сделать так:

1. В корневой VM определить свойство `SelectedItem`, класть в него текущий выбранный элемент. (Кажется, это можно сделать через `OneWay`-привязку к `SelectedItem`.)
2. VM-элементы в разных уровнях дерева имеют разный тип, правильно? Тогда вы кладёте рядом с деревом `<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding SelectedItem}"/>`.
3. Чтобы разные типы отображались по-разному, вам нужно будет определить `DataTemplate`'ы:

   ```
   <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:BlueVM}">
       <view:SomeUserControl/>
   </DataTemplate>

   <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:RedVM}">
       <view:AnotherUserControl/>
   </DataTemplate>
   ```

   и так далее.